# Dynamic AND/OR condition formation Express/Node with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Basically i want to search/filter data with different filters. filters that may be price, gender and also with price range. if gender/price filter not applied so it would not be included in it.

```
getSearchData = async (req, res) => {
    try{

        let obj={ 
                    $or:[
                            {'name': {$regex: new RegExp(req.query.search, 'i')}}, 
                            {'classes': {$regex: new RegExp(req.query.search, 'i')}},
                            {'subjects': {$regex: new RegExp(req.query.search, 'i')}}
                        ],
                    $and:[
                            {'gender': req.query.gender},
                            {'tution_fee': {$gt : req.query.tution_fee_start, $lt : req.query.tution_fee_end}}
                        ]
                };
        console.log(obj);       
        let sortObject = {};
        let sortby = req.query.sortby;
        let sortorder = req.query.sortorder;
        sortObject[sortby] = sortorder;
        return res.json({response: await User.find(obj).sort(sortObject)}) 
    }catch(err){
        return res.json({error: err}) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use plain JS to simplify things?

```
let obj = {
    $or: [
        { 'name': { $regex: new RegExp(req.query.search, 'i') } },
        { 'classes': { $regex: new RegExp(req.query.search, 'i') } },
        { 'subjects': { $regex: new RegExp(req.query.search, 'i') } }
    ]
};

if(req.query.gender){
    obj.$and = (obj.$and || []);
    obj.$and.push({ 'gender': req.query.gender });
}
if(req.query.tution_fee_start && req.query.tution_fee_end){
    obj.$and = (obj.$and || []);
    obj.$and.push({ 'tution_fee': { $gt: parseInt(req.query.tution_fee_start), $lt: parseInt(req.query.tution_fee_end) } });
}
```

Comment: what do you mean not working can you console log the `obj` and paste the output where `req.query.tution_fee_start && req.query.tution_fee_end` is true?

Comment: Hey Aritra,Thanks for the answer. {"$or":[{"name":{"$regex":{}}},{"classes":{"$regex":{}}},{"subjects":{"$regex":{}}}],"$and":[{"tution_fee":{"$gt":"0","$lt":"150"}}]}  .. I had 1000+ records which match this criteria but getting the output like...."response": {
        "docs": [],
        "total": 0,
        "limit": 10,
        "offset": 0
    }

Comment: It's because in the $gt, $lt instead of integers you are putting string. Edited the answer,

Comment: Used this parseInt(req.query.tution_fee_start) but still not working.

Comment: The problem is most probably with the regex instead of RegExp try with string though regexp works fine